# Loading an array of pixel values in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have a 32-bit integer array containing pixel values of a 3450x3450 image I want to create a Mat image with. Tried the following:

```
int *image_array;
image_array = (int *)malloc( 3450*3450*sizeof(int) );
memset( (char *)image_array, 0, sizeof(int)*3450*3450 );
image_array[0] = intensity_of_first_pixel;
...
image_array[11902499] = intensity_of_last_pixel;
Mat M(3450, 3450, CV_32FC1, image_array);
```

and upon displaying the image I get a black screen. I should also note the array contains a 16-bit grayscale image.

Comment: What does `image_array` point to? Could you please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should try to convert the input image, which I assume is in RGB[A] format using:

```
cv::Mat m(3450, 3450, CV_8UC1, image_array) // For GRAY image
cv::Mat m(3450, 3450, CV_8UC3, image_array) // For RGB image
cv::Mat m(3450, 3450, CV_8UC4, image_array) // For RGBA image
```

Comment: The code for the RGBA image format works, but it has a [blue hue](http://i.imgur.com/aVMGrrv.png) for some reason. This is the [result](http://i.imgur.com/XjbEFIZ.png) I should I get. I should note that the image is a 16-bit grayscale.

Comment: OpenCV uses BGR rather than RGB ordering. You need cvtColor() with RGB2BGR

Comment: @ZdaR I've tried `cv::Mat m(3450, 3450, CV_8UC1, image_array) ` and it ended up giving me [this](http://i.imgur.com/MmV9NW8.png).